# MySQL cache is not getting hit by subqueries

Tags: mysql, cache, subquery

I noticed something weird on MySQL query_cache behavior and I would like to know if this is a normal behavior.

Let's say I have an item table

```
 ID | Item
-----------
 1  | Item_1
 2  | Item_2
 3  | Item_3
```

The query that will be used here is : `SELECT id FROM items`

The first time I use it I have a +1 in my status Qcache_inserts, the second time I use it I have +1 to Qcache_hits. Perfect it's working fine.

Now if I use this query : `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT id FROM items) my_table`

The subquery `SELECT id FROM items` is supposed to already be present in the cache, but I can't get any hit.

Aren't subquery simple thread that executes first ? Then why it is not hitting my query cache ?

Comment: Whilst it is called a subquery, it isn't processed (and therefore cached) as a separate query.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL current 5.1 and 5.5 versions do not cache subqueries. Only whole queries. Subqueries are not processed as a separate item and the execution planned created is for the whole query.

MariaDB (a MySQL fork), version 5.3 has an optimization feature that does exactly that: [Subquery cache](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/subquery-cache).

If I am not wrong a similar feature will be incorporated in MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is too simplified.  Let's investigate your *real* question.  Please present SHOW CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN.

In general, I say "turn off the QC".  This is especially important if data is constant flowing into your main tables.  Note that *all* queries for a table (in the QC) are flushed *every* time a write occurs to the table.